# how can i render content of two table by id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two project, stage and task scaffold in rails. i project has one to many association with stage and stage has one to many association with task. i render project with associated stage in project#show but i am not able to render task by their associated stage. Currently all task gets rendered on every stage. 
routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks
    end
  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes(:stages).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
    @tasks = Task.all
  end
```

project show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_project_stage_url(@project), :class=>"button primary small" %>
<br>

<div class="table-scroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Planned start date</th>
        <th>Planned end date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @stages.each do |stage| %>
        <tr class="stage">
          <td><%= stage.stage %></td>
          <td><%= stage.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
          <td><%= stage.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>   
          <% end %>
        </tr>

        <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= task.task_name %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have `has_many :tasks` in stage, you can get each stage tasks via corresponding association.

To avoin N+1 condition preload tasks for each stage:

```
@project = Project.includes(stages: :tasks).find(params[:id])
```

and in you view loop over them:

```
<% stage.tasks.each do |task| %>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. on the same page i have to add new task form path how can i do that?  "<%= link_to "Add Stage", new_project_stage_task_url(@project) %>" this generates error

Comment: task is nested under stages and projects, it's route and corresponding helper need both project and stage

Comment: new_project_stage_task_url(@project, @stage)?

Comment: @mick you do not have `@stage`(instance variable of the controller), only local variable `stage` (this is different on loop iterations)